# copying parameters from one PreparedStatement to another

Tags: java, jdbc, copy, prepared-statement

I create a new PreparedStatement like this:

```
PreparedStatement newPs = origPrepStatement.getConnection().prepareStatement("EXPLAIN " + sql);
```

origPrepStatement is also Preparedstatement and it contains parameters.
I'd like to copy the parameters of origPrepStatement to newPs.
Is there away to do that?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4691561/2168879

Comment: that's sad:-( I don't need it for debugging, I need it for other purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no easy solution; find my clumsy solution below

```
class PreparedStatementParameters implements InvocationHandler {
    Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    PreparedStatement ps;

    PreparedStatementParameters(PreparedStatement ps) {
        this.ps = ps;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if (method.getName().startsWith("set")) {

        }
        return method.invoke(proxy, args);
    }

    public void copyParameters(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Object> e : map.entrySet()) {
            ps.setObject(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    }
}

public class T2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PreparedStatement ps1 = ...
    PreparedStatementParameters ps1params = new PreparedStatementParameters(ps1);
        PreparedStatement ps1Proxy = (PreparedStatement) Proxy.newProxyInstance(null,
                new Class[] { PreparedStatement.class }, new PreparedStatementParameters(ps1));
        ps1Proxy.setString(1, "test");
        ...
        PreparedStatement ps2 = ...
        ps1params.copyParameters(ps2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens here?
if (method.getName().startsWith("set")) {
}

Comment: All parameters that you set on ps1 will be saved in  PreparedStatementParameters